# Is it possible to select an an element that immediately precedes another element using the adjacent selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to select `<label>` elements that immediately precede `<input type="checkbox">`

from the [CSS guide](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

> Adjacent sibling selectors have the
>   following syntax: E1 + E2, where E2 is
>   the subject of the selector.

But, unless I'm misunderstanding the spec I need a select where E1 is the subject not E2.  I'm sure this must be available, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually no, youre not missing anything (unless i have been for quite some time now as well) - you cant select a previous sibling with css2 selectors.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used it, but I understand from the link that you've provided that it should be done exactly like follows:

```
input[type='checkbox'] + label { color: Red }
```

This should work for the next HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='chckTest' /><label>Test checkbox</label>
```

I don't have the possibility to check it now but I believe that the "Test checkbox" text will be red...

Comment: Actually, <label> will be red.